# Xamarin iOS: Unable to set constraints on Controls from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-autolayout

Here setting constraints
[image]I want to set constrains on `UIImageView` so as to control look fit in all screens.
After switching to *Constraint Editing Mode* I set contraints for device 1 (say iPhone X), Than I am selecting another device (say iPhone SE) and setting constraints for it. Now when I switch layout for iPhone X it got disturbed, How can I set constraints properly. I am using Visual Studio 2017 in Windows machine connected to MAC through network.
Please see the attached screenshots. 1st iphone X and 2nd iPhone SE
[image]

[image]

Comment: As I can see its your launch storyboard. I dont know what is issue with you but Could you please let me know whether do you want image in centre of screen or something else.

Comment: @Gagan Yes i need imageview in center as this is launch screen it should show image in center for all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the **sufficient** constraints on that imageView.
To make the image center in the view , you should define its position and size.

```
###Align: 
CenterX to:Superview=0
CenterY to:Superview=0

###Size:
Width=something
Height=something
```

Then you can see the same effect on that image with all kinds of devices.

Comment: @Xia I have tried giving Position still it is not having equal position to all devices. Please see my updated question i have attached  screenshot.

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal It seems that you don't set centerX and centerY, can  you attach the screenshot of  which constraints you have set on(under Properties-> Layout-> Constraints)

Comment: Already I attached screenshot in question itself please check once.

Comment: I want to see those constraints not arrange.

Comment: @Xia see the updated screenshot but i am not able to find exactly where to set constrains

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal  I see you set width ,height , top constraints on that image , it is not sufficient to define the Position.  Refer to official tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/#Center_Constraints

Comment: Do you have any question?@PriyankaAgrawal

Comment: No, as my questions is, I have solved my issue and made some miner changes in your answer. Now I am able to put ImageView in center by using above constrains. You just nailed it. :)

Comment: Hi,Could you mark it so that  it will be helpful for others.

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal Thanks.